# spotinst_sdk2.client.SpotinstClientException: Error encountered while creating account

Tags: terraform

While trying to run `terraform apply` I'm getting the following error:

```
│ Error: local-exec provisioner error
│ 
│   with module.spotinst-aws-connect.null_resource.account,
│   on .terraform/modules/spotinst-aws-connect/main.tf line 12, in resource "null_resource" "account":
│   12:     provisioner "local-exec" {
│ 
│ Error running command '.terraform/modules/spotinst-aws-connect/scripts/spot_account_aws.py create my-organization --token=XXX': exit status 1. Output:
│ Traceback (most recent call last):
│   File "/home/kadu/src/fnix/infra/.terraform/modules/spotinst-aws-connect/scripts/spot_account_aws.py", line 147, in <module>
│     cli()
│   File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
│     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
│   File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
│     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
│   File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
│     return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
│   File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
│     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
│   File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
│     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
│   File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
│     return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
│   File "/home/kadu/src/fnix/infra/.terraform/modules/spotinst-aws-connect/scripts/spot_account_aws.py", line 30, in create
│     result = ctx.obj['client'].create_account(kwargs.get('name'))
│   File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spotinst_sdk2-2.1.18-py3.10.egg/spotinst_sdk2/clients/admin/__init__.py", line 118, in create_account
│     response = self.send_post(
│   File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spotinst_sdk2-2.1.18-py3.10.egg/spotinst_sdk2/client.py", line 152, in send_post
│     self.handle_exception("creating {}".format(entity_name), result)
│   File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spotinst_sdk2-2.1.18-py3.10.egg/spotinst_sdk2/client.py", line 231, in handle_exception
│     raise SpotinstClientException(
│ spotinst_sdk2.client.SpotinstClientException: Error encountered while creating account
```

I don't know what I can do to get more information about what is going wrong, any help is very appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm using the free plan of spotinst and it allows only one account. If I delete the actual it automatically creates a new one.

Comment: I upgrade to the basic plan. I can create new accounts throw the console, but still get the same error running `terraform apply`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the free plan was a problem for my scenario, but the Spotinst API appears to have some issues. After digging into the python SDK and making changes, I could expose more information.

These are consecutive outputs for the command: `/bin/sh -c ".terraform/modules/spotinst-aws-connect/scripts/spot_account_aws.py get --token=my-api-token`

First run:

```
Sending get request to spotinst API.
Success
{"account_id": "xxx", "organization_id": "xxx", "name": "xxx", "cloud_provider": null, "provider_external_id": null, "created_at": "2022-08-27T23:29:35.000+0000"}
```

Second run:

```
Sending get request to spotinst API.
403
{"status": {"code": 403, "message": "Forbidden"}, "errors": [{"code": "ACCESS_DENIED", "message": "You don't have permissions to access this endpoint"}]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kadu/src/fnix/infra/.terraform/modules/spotinst-aws-connect/scripts/spot_account_aws.py", line 148, in <module>
    cli()
  File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click-8.1.3-py3.10.egg/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kadu/src/fnix/infra/.terraform/modules/spotinst-aws-connect/scripts/spot_account_aws.py", line 128, in get
    result = ctx.obj['client'].get_accounts()
  File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spotinst_sdk2-2.1.18-py3.10.egg/spotinst_sdk2/clients/admin/__init__.py", line 139, in get_accounts
    response = self.send_get(
  File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spotinst_sdk2-2.1.18-py3.10.egg/spotinst_sdk2/client.py", line 73, in send_get
    self.handle_exception("getting {}".format(entity_name), result)
  File "/home/kadu/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spotinst_sdk2-2.1.18-py3.10.egg/spotinst_sdk2/client.py", line 231, in handle_exception
    raise SpotinstClientException(
spotinst_sdk2.client.SpotinstClientException: Error encountered while getting account
```

I guess that the initial problem is exactly the same thing, Spotinst API forbade the requests.